# How to insert macrons without using the compose key?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, configuration, keyboard

I'm on Ubuntu 19.04, and I would like to know a good way for inserting macrons, ā/ē/ī/ō/ū, without using the compose key. I'm currently dealing with a bunch of Latin, and these are essential to the spellings of vocabulary. Ideally, what I would like to do is press a and then - quickly together to make ā. If I press the keys together a bit slower then I would get both of the characters next to each other like 'a-'. I wonder how to do this? I am using i3wm, but I would be curious on how to do this in either Gnome or KDE as well. I am currently using the compose key, but this is pretty cumbersome. Thanks!

Comment: In which text editor?

Comment: The Compose key is ideal for this in my experience; is there a reason you don't want to use it?  That asked, `vim` has `digraph` as a setting you can try.

Comment: I would ideally like to do this globally, so that I don't have to do this in any particular text editor, but I do use vim. I know how to insert with Ctrl-k and then it acts like the compose key. The main reason that I don't want to use the compose key is that it is heavily inefficient when I am typing a large amount of text.

Comment: I've gotten used to the compose key, so I'm going to mark this as done.